# Need to remove iframe element with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to remove iframe banner of the free version.
From this player http://techadvantage.co/development/web-applications/flexible-radio-player

```
$('iframe #flexible-radio-player').remove();
```

this code not working
can you help me ? :)

Comment: you can't edit a iframe because of the CORS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#flexible-radio-player').remove();
```

Or

```
$('iframe[id="flexible-radio-player"]').remove();
```

Comment: Try replacing `.remove()` with `.empty()`

Comment: ohh so you're trying to remove an element which is inside iframe? The link you sent me had an iframe with id = "flexible-radio-playing". I misunderstood it previously. I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.